# How to get the output for the following?

Tags: perl

I have a file which looks something like this

```
#define PIOMUX2_UART_3_RXD   CONFIG_PIO31_5_SELECTOR,   ALT_2,   CONFIG_SYSCFG_PIO31_5_OE,   I
#define PIOMUX2_UART_3_TXD   CONFIG_PIO31_6_SELECTOR,   ALT_2,   CONFIG_SYSCFG_PIO31_6_OE,   O
#define PIOMUX2_UART_3_CTS   CONFIG_PIO31_7_SELECTOR,   ALT_1,   CONFIG_SYSCFG_PIO31_7_OE,   I
```

and I need to get like

```
#define PIOMUX2_UART_3_RXD   CONFIG_PIO31_5_SELECTOR
#define PIOMUX2_UART_3_TXD   CONFIG_PIO31_6_SELECTOR
#define PIOMUX2_UART_3_CTS   CONFIG_PIO31_7_SELECTOR
```

i tried this :

```
open my $fh, '>', 'perl_script_3_out_1.txt' or die $!;
while (<$fh>)
{
  s/^ALT//g;
  s/^CONFIG_SYS//g;
  s/,//g; print $_;
}
close($fh);
```

Comment: open my $fh, '>', 'perl_script_3_out_1.txt' or die $!;
while (<$fh>) {
  
s/^ALT//g;
 s/^CONFIG_SYS//g;
 s/,//g;
print $_;
}
close($fh);

Comment: I am new to it and not sure I am just tryng and learning as I am coming across new issues

Comment: You are writing in file instead of reading. Change `>` with `<`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your primary issue is that you are opening a file in write mode (`'>'`) but then trying to read from it (`<$fh>`.)

Your second issue is that you are anchoring your substitution regular expressions to the beginning of the line (`s/^...`) but none of your input lines begin with ALT or CONFIG_SYS, because they all begin with #define.

Try something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'input.txt' or die $!;

while (<$fh>) {
    s/,.+//;
    print;
}
close $fh;
```

Which runs like this:

```
alex@yuzu:~$ perl stack.pl
#define PIOMUX2_UART_3_RXD   CONFIG_PIO31_5_SELECTOR
#define PIOMUX2_UART_3_TXD   CONFIG_PIO31_6_SELECTOR
#define PIOMUX2_UART_3_CTS   CONFIG_PIO31_7_SELECTOR
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

Simple `grep` function is enough for you.

```
open my $handle, '<', 'file.txt' or die $!;
my @ar =  grep{~s/,.+//g} <$handle>;
print @ar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# cat test 
#define PIOMUX2_UART_3_RXD   CONFIG_PIO31_5_SELECTOR,   ALT_2,   CONFIG_SYSCFG_PIO31_5_OE,   I
#define PIOMUX2_UART_3_TXD   CONFIG_PIO31_6_SELECTOR,   ALT_2,   CONFIG_SYSCFG_PIO31_6_OE,   O
#define PIOMUX2_UART_3_CTS   CONFIG_PIO31_7_SELECTOR,   ALT_1,   CONFIG_SYSCFG_PIO31_7_OE,   I

# perl -a -F, -lne 'print $F[0]' test 
#define PIOMUX2_UART_3_RXD   CONFIG_PIO31_5_SELECTOR
#define PIOMUX2_UART_3_TXD   CONFIG_PIO31_6_SELECTOR
#define PIOMUX2_UART_3_CTS   CONFIG_PIO31_7_SELECTOR
```

For perl command line parameter explanation, please refer: https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/the_top_10_tricks_of

@Grace90, for given sample data, look at file from a column perspective. Also, consider all these columns are separated by a comma. So, in a nutshell, you want to extract the 1st column of the file which has its columns separated by comma.

So for above command line:

`-F,` defines the comma as a field separator.
Once each line of the file is split, it is saved in an array `F`.
and then I am printing only the 1st element of this array which is `$f[0]`

Answer (score 0):

You could resolve it in the command line:

```
perl -p -i.bak -e "s/([^,]+),.*/$1/" my_data_file.txt
```

This change your data file (my_data_file.txt), and creates a backup (my_data_file.bak)

Answer (score -2):

By using `split` function also you can get the output.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open my $fh, '<', 'file.txt' or die $!;
while (<$fh>)
{
  my @data = split(',', $_);
  print "$data[0]\n";
}
close($fh);
```